# Enhance performace for custom code

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I need to make this code faster and consume less memory.

```
 makeBZ001[x_] := Module[{dat = x, rt1, rt2, rt3, temp1, temp2, temp3,rm, tempfull,full, bool1, res}, 
 rt1 = ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}]; temp1 = dat;
 temp1[[All, 1 ;; 2]] = rt1[temp1[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]; 
 rt2 = ReflectionTransform[{1, 0}]; 
 temp2 = DeleteDuplicates[Join[dat, temp1]]; 
 temp2[[All, 1 ;; 2]] = rt2[temp2[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]; 
 rt3 = ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]; 
 temp3 = DeleteDuplicates[Join[dat, temp1, temp2]]; 
 temp3[[All, 1 ;; 2]] = rt3[temp3[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]; 
 tempfull = DeleteDuplicates[Join[dat, temp1, temp2, temp3]]; 
 bool1 = RegionMember[Polygon[{{0., 1.}, {-1., 0.}, {0., -1.},{1.,0.}}]]/@ tempfull[[All, 1 ;; 2]]; 
 res = Pick[tempfull, bool1];
 res
 ]

 n = 10^5;
 data1 = ConstantArray[RandomInteger[{-2, 2}], {n, 2}];
 data2 = ConstantArray[RandomInteger[{0, 1}], {n, 21}];
 array = {};
 If[Dimensions[data1][[1]] == Dimensions[data2][[1]], 
 Do[temp = ArrayFlatten[{{data1, Transpose[{data2[[All, j]]}]}}]; 
 temp2 = makeBZ001[temp]; 
 pick = Boole[(NumberQ[#1] &) /@ temp2[[All, -1]]]; 
 temp2[[All, -1]] = temp2[[All, -1]] pick; 
 AppendTo[array, temp2], {j, 2., 21.}];, 
 Print["Dimensions of data1 and data2 are incompatible."]; Abort[];];
 link = Association[];
 m = 1;
 Do[link[ToString[n]] = m; 
 m = m + 1;
 , {n, {j11, j21, j12, j22, L21, L12, R21, R12, l021, l012, r021, r012, jl11, jl21, jl12, jl22, jr11, jr21, jr12, jr22}}
 ]
```

The main idea is to create 20 {~4n,3} lists and reference them by name, such that `array[link[ToString[j11]]]` is just `array[[1]]`. I had to add a part, `pick` variable, to check for numbers like `1.34343-256` which create errors in post processing. I'm looking for any exploit or shortcut to make this faster. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
Just realized the sample data wont work. Here is actual data you can use to test the code.

[data1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GYq988b8m2BxrgmwzwPuYHjhRZanVQr4)

[data2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ef23A96hrCvK0wntuevtVW7zQO1-zGK0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another speed up is to use the "listable" version of [`RegionMemberFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMemberFunction) instead of using [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map). For example:

```
rmf = RegionMember[Polygon[{{0.,1.},{-1.,0.},{0.,-1.},{1.,0.}}]];

pts = RandomReal[{-1,2}, {10^5,2}];

r1 = rmf /@ pts; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = rmf[pts]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1===r2
```

> {0.078793, Null}
>
> {0.005577, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 3):

To start with something: Linear algebra is much faster than this fancy `ReflectionTransform`:

```
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000000, 2}];
y1 = ReflectionTransform[{1, 0}][x]; // AbsoluteTiming
y2 = x.Transpose[ReflectionMatrix[{1, 0}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
y1 == y2

x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000000, 2}];
y1 = ReflectionTransform[{1, 0}][x]; // RepeatedTiming // First
y2 = x.Transpose[ReflectionMatrix[{1, 0}]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
y1 == y2
```

> 0.135
>
> 0.0045
>
> True

Comment: Dot products are very nice in *Mathematica*, so one should always try to use them.